# What happens if you use .BeginTrans and don't use .CommitTrans or .Rollback

Tags: vba, ms-access

What happens if you use .BeginTrans and .Execute then you exit code before .CommitTrans or .Rollback in Access VBA.

Comment: I think if you write beginn tran, then the transaction mode is explicit which means you have to write commit or rollback. If you do not write commit or rollback, the transaction locks would be active until the connection is not closed.

Comment: I tried, and I got a black "Access forbidden" like icon in my table. But I couldn't exactly figure out if changes apply or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel's comment pretty much sums it up. When I run the following code...

```
Sub noCommit()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("tblSampleData", dbOpenTable)
DBEngine.Workspaces(0).BeginTrans
rst.Edit
rst!Item = "Item1amended"
rst.Update
'' no Commit and no Rollback
End Sub
```

...and then open the table in Datasheet view any attempts to edit either of the two records results in a "beep" and the "no entry" icon on the record selector.

[image: noEntry]

Attempts to add a new record are met with a "Could not update" error:

[image: couldNotUpdate]

So, the changes made within the transaction are not written, and the table is left in a locked state until the connection is closed (or the transaction is cleared). Since my transaction was based on the default Access connection (`DBEngine.Workspaces(0)`) that means either closing and re-opening Access, or running the following:

```
Sub transRollback()
DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Rollback
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. so the only thing that happens in back-end is record locking. nothing written, overwritten or deleted.